# Qt subdirs: use common source files

Tags: c++, qt, project

I need to use common **source** files (not library!) for two projects  in Qt. I've created such structure:

```
main
    main.pro
    common.pri
    project1
        project1.pro
    project2
        project2.pro
    shared
        (common *,cpp, *.h, etc)
```

Each `project*.pro` contains a link to `common.pri`:

```
include(../common.pri)
```

`common.pri`:

```
(initial settings)
.........
INCLUDEPATH += ../shared/
DEPENDPATH += ../shared/
UI_SOURCES_DIR += ../shared/
```

So it works, but the files in the `shared` directory seem to be "ownerless" and are not shown in Qt Creator. My question is, is that right, or should I add each common file into project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those source files don't belong to a project, they won't show up in the *Projects* view. But if you have a *common* folder in that very view, which refers to the *common.pri*, just right-click on it and use *Add existing directory ...* to add the *shared* folder and have the stray files in the view.

I don't really know what's preventing you to put the common files in a **static** library, but I guess you know that would be a better practice ...